# Can the power button be reassigned in red hat 8 gnome?

Tags: linux, shutdown, gnome, redhat-enterprise-linux

I don't mean the physical power button, but the dekstop power button one would use to power off or reboot the system.

I guess, that if you click on reboot, or shutdown, internally it probably just calls /bin/systemctl reboot, or poweroff.

Is it possible to change that? If I click the button, I would like to run a shell script and then do the reboot/shutdown.

I have read some stuff about polkit, but that post was like 8 years ago and for ubuntu.

Is that possible in the current red hat 8 gnome desktop?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather want to run this script for all shutdown actions, not just for this button?

Comment: sure. I managed to do it for CLI shutdowns by creating a symlink for /sbin/shutdown, but that does not work for the button

Comment: Please don't do that, you're asking for trouble. [How to run a script with systemd right before shutdown?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39226)